# Rappid.js - getScreenCTM returns null in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, jointjs, rappid

I have encountered a problem that is causing me some headaches over the past few days.

I have a web page where users can create sort of a sequence diagram (using joint.js and rappid.js v1.7.1). The idea is - an user has some nodes available that can be dragged onto a canvas (paper in joint.js) and then these nodes can be linked with each other.

The functionality on itself works great in chrome and internet explorer, but I can't seem to get it to work in Firefox (Version  47.0.1).

As soon as I drop a node on the canvas I get the following error: [image]

As said this error only occurs in Firefox and using the Firefox and Chrome debugger functions I was able to tell that the "same" object does receive a SVG Matrix in Chrome while its null in Firefox.

The Node contains a SVG Image Content:

```
defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'stations.StartPoint',
    attrs: {
        '.stations-point-title-text': { 'text': 'Start' },
        '.stations-point-content-image': { "xlink:href": "data:image/svg+xml;base64,..." }
    }
}, stations.Point.prototype.defaults)
```

The line of code in rappid.js where the error occurs

```
getTransformToElement: function (a) {
            return a.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.node.getScreenCTM())
        },
```

Has anyone had similar experience with joint.js? Any help or tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

**EDIT:** I found a solution to the issue, although I must confess I don't quite understand it. After analysis of a demo program that worked in Firefox I figured out that the difference was I wasn't calling the Navigator.render() functionality in my code (since I wasn't using a navigator). Adding that call resolved my problem. (http://jointjs.com/rappid/docs/ui/navigator)

Comment: Is an element which is attached to the document? Is it display:none?

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes it is attached to the document and display:block

Comment: Are any of it's ancestors display:none? I think you're going to need to create a [mcve] here.

Comment: I have the same issue. Yet interestingly, the jointjs demo (the FSM one) works in FF!

Comment: @Lior I haven't made much progress on this yet... unfortunately the solution we have is to complex to break down into a minimal verifiable example... What did you move to Version 0.9.5 ? As for Angular2, I'm not using this so, if you tell me what to downgrade to 0.9.5 I can check if I get the same second error as you or not ...

Answer (score 0):

Once moved to 0.9.5 the problem disappears.
But make sure to include in your index.html

> < script >    SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement = SVGElement.prototype.getTransformToElement || function(toElement) {
>           return toElement.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(this.getScreenCTM());
>       };< / script >

Comment: Firefox has a native implementation of getTransformToElement and should not need that code. Chrome would need it but this question is about Firefox.